# Test Cases for Rego Polices

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

Sorry for my novice question. I have written a rego rule to check for ASV Names, and now I am looking to write a test case for the same. I have looked at sample test cases but has no success in writing for my policy(pasted below). Was wondering how could I get a positive and a failure case for the rule below.

```
asv_list = {"ASVONE","ASVXYZ"} 
check_asv := { resources[i]: Reason |
    resources:=[resource | data[j] ;
        list := {x| x:=asv_list[_]}
        not(list[data[j].ASV])
        resource:=data[j].Name]
        
    Reason := sprintf("THE ASV - %v being used is not a valid ASV", [data[j].ASV])
}

data = {resource |
    doc = input[i];
        key_ids := [k | doc[k]; startswith(k, "tag."); k != "tag.#"; endswith(k, ".key")]
    resource := {
        doc[k] : doc[replace(k, ".key", ".value")] | key_ids[_] == k
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to test `check_asv` your positive and negative test cases will look similar:

- Define input value
- Define expected value
- Assert that `check_asv` is equal to expected value when evaluated with test input

For example:

```
test_check_asv_positive {
  expected := {"r1": "..."} 
  fake_input := [{"Name": "foo", ...}]
  check_asv == expected with input as fake_input
}
```

Before you start writing tests for your rule though, I think you should clarify the logic you're trying to express because there are a few red flags that jump out. I've tried to breakdown the issues I see in the policy below. At the end, I've written out some example test cases.

## Format the file to make it easier to read

First of all, just format the Rego so that it's easier to read. I  pasted your example into a file, added a `package` (to make it a valid .rego file) and then ran `opa fmt file.rego`:

```
asv_list = {"ASVONE", "ASVXYZ"}

check_asv := {resources[i]: Reason |
        resources := [resource |
                data[j]
                list := {x | x := asv_list[_]}
                not list[data[j].ASV]
                resource := data[j].Name
        ]

        Reason := sprintf("THE ASV - %v being used is not a valid ASV", [data[j].ASV])
}

data = {resource |
        doc = input[i]
        key_ids := [k |
                doc[k]
                startswith(k, "tag.")
                k != "tag.#"
                endswith(k, ".key")
        ]

        resource := {doc[k]: doc[replace(k, ".key", ".value")] |
                key_ids[_] == k
        }
}
```

This a little bit easier to read.

## Do not name rules `data`

I recommend NOT naming that rule `data`. `data` in Rego is a special global variable that refers to state cached inside the policy engine. Any data from outside OPA or generated by rules inside of OPA is accessible under `data`. Defining a rule named `data` is allowed but it's confusing. Rename `data` to something meaningful in the domain. E.g., if these were virtual machine resources, you could name them `vm_resources`. In this case, I don't have much to go on, so I'm going to rename it to `input_docs` since `doc` was used as a variable name:

```
check_asv := {resources[i]: Reason |
        resources := [resource |
                input_docs[j]
                list := {x | x := asv_list[_]}
                not list[input_docs[j].ASV]
                resource := input_docs[j].Name
        ]

        Reason := sprintf("THE ASV - %v being used is not a valid ASV", [input_docs[j].ASV])
}

input_docs = {resource |
        doc = input[i]
        key_ids := [k |
                doc[k]
                startswith(k, "tag.")
                k != "tag.#"
                endswith(k, ".key")
        ]

        resource := {doc[k]: doc[replace(k, ".key", ".value")] |
                key_ids[_] == k
        }
}
```

## Simplify the `input_docs` helper rule (which was called `data` in the original)

At first glance, this rule is doing quite a bit of work, but in reality, it's not. The first line (`doc = input[i]`) just iterates over each element in `input`. The rest of the rule is based on each element in `input`. The second expression, `key_ids := [...`, computes an array of object keys from the element. The third expression, `resources := {doc[k]: ...`, constructs a new object by mapping the element.

The first expression can't be simplified much, however, it's better to use `:=` instead of `=` and since `i` is not referenced anywhere else we can just use `_`. The first expression becomes:

```
doc := input[_]
```

The second expression computes an array of keys but the filtering is a bit redundant: `k` cannot be equal to `tag.#` AND end with `.key` so the `!=` expression can be removed:

```
key_ids := [k |
  some k
  doc[k]
  startswith(k, "tag.")
  endswith(k, ".key")
]
```

At this point we could stop however it's worth noticing that the second and third expression in the rule are both just iterating over the `doc` object. There's no reason for two separate expressions here. To simplify this rule we can combine them:

```
input_docs = {resource |        
        doc := input[_]
        resource := {v: x |
                some k
                v := doc[k]
                startswith(k, "tag.")
                endswith(k, ".key")
                x := doc[replace(k, ".key", ".value")]
        }
}
```

## Simplify the `check_asv` rule

Now that we have a simplified version of the `input_docs` rule that generates a set of mapped resources we can focus on the `check_asv` rule. The `check_asv` rule can be simplified quite a bit:

1. Multiple iterators in the rule body (`i` and `j`) when there should be only one.
2. Construction of invalid resource list is overly complex.

The rule can be simplified down to the following:

```
check_asv := {name: reason |
        r := input_docs[_]
        not asv_list[r.ASV]
        name := r.Name
        reason := sprintf("THE ASV - %v being used is not a valid ASV", [r.ASV])
}
```

- No need to iterate over `input_docs` twice (in fact this would be incorrect.)
- No need for a nested comprehension.
- No need constructing a set from `asv_list`, it's already a set.

## Putting it all together

At this point the policy looks like this:

```
asv_list = {"ASVONE", "ASVXYZ"}

check_asv := {name: reason |
        r := input_docs[_]
        not asv_list[r.ASV]
        name := r.Name
        reason := sprintf("THE ASV - %v being used is not a valid ASV", [r.ASV])
}

input_docs = {resource |        
        doc := input[_]
        resource := {v: x |
                some k
                v := doc[k]
                startswith(k, "tag.")
                endswith(k, ".key")
                x := doc[replace(k, ".key", ".value")]
        }
}
```

To test this policy we can easily write a few test cases:

```
test_check_asv_positive {
    exp := {
        "dog": "THE ASV - ASVBAD being used is not a valid ASV"
    }
    
    inp := [
       {
           "tag.foo.key": "Name",
           "tag.foo.value": "dog",
           "tag.bar.key": "ASV",
           "tag.bar.value": "ASVBAD"
       }
   ]
    
    check_asv == exp with input as inp
}

test_check_asv_positive_multiple_resources {
    exp := {
        "dog": "THE ASV - ASVBAD being used is not a valid ASV",
        "horse": "THE ASV - ASVBAD2 being used is not a valid ASV"
    }
    
    inp := [
       {
           "tag.foo.key": "Name",
           "tag.foo.value": "dog",
           "tag.bar.key": "ASV",
           "tag.bar.value": "ASVBAD"
       },
       {
           "tag.foo.key": "Name",
           "tag.foo.value": "horse",
           "tag.bar.key": "ASV",
           "tag.bar.value": "ASVBAD2"
       }
   ]
    
    check_asv == exp with input as inp
}


test_check_asv_positive_multiple_resources_mixed {
    exp := {
        "horse": "THE ASV - ASVBAD2 being used is not a valid ASV"
    }
    
    inp := [
       {
           "tag.foo.key": "Name",
           "tag.foo.value": "cat",
           "tag.bar.key": "ASV",
           "tag.bar.value": "ASVONE"
       },
       {
           "tag.foo.key": "Name",
           "tag.foo.value": "horse",
           "tag.bar.key": "ASV",
           "tag.bar.value": "ASVBAD2"
       }
   ]
    
    check_asv == exp with input as inp
}


test_check_asv_negative {
    exp := {}
    
    inp := [
       {
           "tag.foo.key": "Name",
           "tag.foo.value": "cat",
           "tag.bar.key": "ASV",
           "tag.bar.value": "ASVONE"
       }
   ]
    
    check_asv == exp with input as inp
}
```

Here's a link to the full policy in the playground: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/6w7aC9xWYH